# Get inserted ID with CakePHP without working with model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to get the ID from an INSERT query with CAKEPHP.
In this case I'm not working with the Model itself so I'm not using the following code:

```
$this->ModelName->save($data);

//Then...

$this->ModelName->getInsertID();
$this->ModelName->getLastInsertID();
```

I'm just using

```
$this->query("INSERT.......");
```

How can I get the Inserted ID with CakePHP without referencing the model?

Comment: Well, why are you not using the ORM?

Comment: I'm just not using ORM in this case, I need to save this fast, it is temporary. Beyond this I would like to know a solution for a case of this type.

Comment: Err... can you provide a proof that the ORM is so much slower than calling the query() directly? I highly doubt that. If you're concerned about performance, why are you using SQL at all and not Redis or something else for whatever you try? Honestly this sounds like an excuse to not use the ORM but write potentially unsecure SQL.

Comment: I'm not arguing about the virtues of ORM. I'm looking for a way to do this. If you don't know how to do this please let someone with experience tell us.

Comment: @RobertPlant what burzum is suggesting is simply follow the standards, you are using a framework for a reason, right? using Model::query is not faster than the regular Model::save method. Actually, Model::query is slower, insecure and makes your code hard to read and maintain.

Comment: The reason I talked about the word "fast" was about implementing someting temporary without using ORM, a "fast" solution, because this is something temporary. I'm not talking about the speed of the methods. Arilia answered OK.

Comment: That's really an awkward argument. I don't see you typing much less with query() than using save() and the getLastInsertId() method. Plus the disadvantages that come with plain SQL. And practice like that usually turns out in "Oh it works somehow, lets keep it.". And I don't think you're going to be faster with your practice if you claim that you will do it right later, you do it twice then.

Comment: That's just your point of view. Have a beautiful day! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the query is beeing cached.

If you see the logs the query isn't even been executed (I tried your code)

try this instead

```
$this->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();" , false);
```

see manual

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
```

See [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: Thanks Oswald, but if I'm in a foreach, $this->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'); repeats the same ID.

Comment: From the documentation: If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted row only.

Comment: No, just insert a row every time I pass by the foreach:

foreach($array as $item)
{

$sql1 = $this->query("INSERT INTO contenidos (id, titulo) VALUES ('NULL','".$item['titulo']."')");
print_r($this->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'));

}

Comment: Of what class is `$this`? Are you sure that the return value of `$this->query()` has the meaning that you think it has?

Comment: you need to load model before quering for last insert id

Comment: Moyed, please read the first question. Oswald: Yes, i'm shure that has the meaning I think. The first value I get is OK (is the first of the foreach). Try it by yourself. Make an empty Class, for example an array with 3 values, and make a foreach with a $this->query("INSERT..."); and print the LAST_INSERT_ID() every time you pass the foreach.

Comment: An empty class does not have a `query()` method. Of what class is `$this`? I do not know CakePHP, but I can read the documentation if I knew which one.

Comment: Think like you have a class that is not referenced to a database, just a class with functions and inside a method you just wan't to make an insert and then bring the ID.

Comment: Maybe he is in a tipical cake Model class linked to a mysql table and he simply doesen't want to use cake functions but prefers to query directly del DB. For some reasons that he doesn't wants to explain. Anyway I tested his code and i see that the last_insert_id query is executed only the first time

Comment: That's right arilia! :) last_insert_id is executed only the first time.